# I am learning Flask and I am facing this issue

Tags: python, flask, backend

I am learning Flask. I wrote the basic code and I want the submitted text to display in the same page. I already wrote the html and connected it. How can I do this?

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for,render_template, request

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"]) 
def home(): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        user = request.form["nm"] 
        return redirect(url_for("/", user)) 
    else: 
        return render_template("login.html")

if name == ("main"): 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: nm is from HTML file

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that you've taken the code from [Python Basics](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/). Indeed they do not show how to format the HTML template of the redirect.

Luckily, they offer a tutorial that shows you how to feed retrieved data to an HTML template using Jinja2. This tutorial can be found [here](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-template-data). In essence, you can use `{{ variable }}` in your HTML template. In Flask, you will have to specify the variable as argument in the `render_template` function.

**Minimal example:**

```
# app.py
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      variable = request.form['variable']
      return render_template("result.html", variable=variable)
```

```
<!-- result.html -->
<p> This is your variable: {{ variable }} </p>
```

I advice you to also check out both the [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) and [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) documentation, as they offer plenty comprehensive examples of how to work with callbacks and HTML templating.